# How does block beneficiary work? What's the point?

Tags: cpp-ethereum

From [Gavin Wood's yellow paper](http://gavwood.com/paper.pdf):

> In general, Ether used to purchase gas that is not refunded is
>   delivered to the beneficiary address, the address of an account
>   typically under the control of the miner.

This looks like a way to tip the miner. I'm trying to understand how it works.

Inside a transaction, there are:

- `value` field is the amount of ether to transfer to the recipient. So
  the tip paid to the beneficiary shouldn't be included here.
- `gasLimit` field is the max gas to pay the gas costs of the contract 
  steps. Any unused gas will be re-funded. Is there a mechanism for the
  sender to say to miner: "Hey why don't you keep the change? "

I looked at other fields but they all seem to be unrelated. So how does this work?

Also, since sender can set `gasPrice` higher which can be a way to tip the miner, so what's the point of including another way of tipping?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Ether used to purchase gas that is not refunded" is a poorly worded way to say "transaction fee."

`value` is the amount of the transaction and has nothing to do with the mining. If I send you ten ether, you get ten ether.

`gasLimit` is the max amount in gas you're willing to pay for the transaction. It's in addition to the value.

`gasUsed` (which you don't mention) is the amount of gas actually used for the calculation which will always be less than or equal to `gasLimit`.

`gasUsed` times `gasPrice` calculates out to be the max amount of ether you're willing to pay to have the transaction processed. In other words, the transaction fee. (It's not a tip because it is not optional.  If you don't pay the gas, your transaction will most likely not get processed.)

Comment: The paper also says `It is named gasLimit since any unused gas at the
end of the transaction is refunded (at the same rate of purchase)
to the sender’s account.` So the transaction fee (that goes to miner beneficiary) should be equal to actually used amount of gas times `gasPrice` and the rest will be refunded. Is that right?

Comment: That is correct. I corrected my post.